# Sequence in p-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory

Can we show the sequence x$_n$ = 1 $-$ ($\frac{1}{2}$)$^{n!}$ converges to 0 in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?  (p is a prime number, which is not 2 and 3)

I mean it seems that |1 $-$ ($\frac{1}{2}$)$^{n!}$|$_p$ = $\frac{1}{p^b}$, where b = ord$_p$(1 $-$ ($\frac{1}{2}$)$^{n!}$). Since p does not divide 1 $-$ ($\frac{1}{2}$)$^{n!}$, b = 0. Then |1 $-$ ($\frac{1}{2}$)$^{n!}$|$_p$ = 1 $\neq$ 0.

Comment: $1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n!} = \frac{2^{n!}-1}{2^{n!}}$. Why do you say $p$ does not divide $2^{n!}-1$?

Comment: e.g. $\frac{2^6-1}{2^6}=\frac{63}{2^6}$, so $\operatorname{ord}_7(1-(1/2)^{3!})=1$ and 

$\frac{2^{24}-1}{2^{24}} = \frac{16777215}{2^{24}} = \frac{3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 241}{2^{24}}$ and so on

Comment: okay, thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The original question was to show that $(1 - (1/2)^{n!})$ converges to 0 in $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p \neq 2,3$. It is enough to show that an arbitrarily large power of $p$ divides $2^{n!}-1$ for $n \gg 0$.

The solution to the edited question is easy since the only factor of $3^{n!}$ is 3...

---

Here is my solution to the original question:

So, the goal is to show that for all $k>0$, there exists $n \gg 0$ so that $p^k | 2^{n!}-1$.

In looking for lots of factors, it's useful to notice that for any positive integers $n,m$,

$(2^{nm}-1) = (2^n - 1)(1 + 2^n + 2^{2n} + \cdots + 2^{(m-1)n})$

Therefore, for $n > p-1$, since $(p-1) | n!$, write $r = n!/(p-1)$ and we have

$(2^{n!}-1) = (2^{p-1}-1)(1 + 2^{p-1} + 2^{2(p-1)} + ... + 2^{(r-1)(p-1)})$

By Fermat's little theorem, $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, so also $2^{m(p-1)} \equiv 1 \mod p$ for any positive integer $m$.

Therefore $(1 + 2^{p-1} + 2^{2(p-1)} + ... + 2^{(r-1)(p-1)}) \equiv 1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 \equiv r \mod p$.

Taking $n=p,\quad$ $r = p!/(p-1) \equiv 0 \mod p$, so

$p | 2^{p-1}-1$ and $p | (1 + 2^{p-1} + 2^{2(p-1)} + ... + 2^{(r-1)(p-1)})$, so that

$p^2 | (2^{p!}-1)$.

OK, for higher powers of $p$ we need one more trick

For example, to get $p^3$, choose $n=p^2$ and keep writing $r = n!/(p-1)$. Then

\begin{align*}
1 + 2^{p-1} + 2^{2(p-1)} + ... + 2^{(p-1)(p-1)} + 2^{p(p-1)} + \cdots + 2^{(r-1)(p-1)} =\\
(1 + 2^{p-1} + 2^{2(p-1)} + ... + 2^{(p-1)(p-1)})(1 + 2^{p(p-1)} + 2^{2p(p-1)} + \cdots + 2^{(p-1)p(p-1)})
\end{align*}

Each of the factors has $p$ terms, and each of the terms are congruent to 1 mod $p$, hence each of the factors are congruent to 0 mod $p$.

This shows that $p^3 | 2^{(p^2)!}-1$. Arguing similarly, you can show that $p^k | 2^{(p^{k-1})!}-1$.

Comment: what if we change the sequence to 1 $-$ ($\frac{3}{4}$  )$^{n!}$

Comment: I think similar arguments work to show that for any $p>a$, $p^k$ divides $(a^{(p^{k-1})!}-1)$. Then $4^{n!}-3^{n!} = (4^{n!}-1) - (3^{n!}-1)$, so if $p^k$ divides $(4^{n!}-1)$ and $(3^{n!}-1)$, it also divides their difference.